# Not Found url in django class based view with ajax

Tags: python, jquery, json, ajax, django

I have a problem with "like" functionality. I want to make it possible to like the post, without overloading the whole page. So I used CBV django connected to ajax.

My problem is that it receives: `Not Found: /like/` by pressing the "Like" button.

My view:

```
class PostLikeView(generic.View):
    def post(self, request):

        post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('id'))
        is_liked = False
        if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            post.likes.remove(request.user)
            is_liked = False
        else:
            post.likes.add(request.user)
            is_liked = True
        context = {
            'post': post,
            'is_liked': is_liked,
            'total_likes': post.total_likes(),
            }
        if request.is_ajax():
            html = render_to_string('post/like_section.html', context, request=request)
            return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

Below is jquery code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(event){
                $(document).on('click', '#like', function(event){
                    event.preventDefault;
                    var pk = $(this).attr('value');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: "{% url 'post:post_like' %}",
                        data: {'id': pk, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(response){
                            $('#like-section').html(response['form'])
                            console.log($('#like-section').html(response['form']))
                        },
                        error: function(rs, e){
                            console.log(rs.responseText);
                        },
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

url to view:

```
url(r'^like/$', login_required(PostLikeView.as_view()), name='post_like'),
```

code in html:

```
<form action="{% url 'post:post_like' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if is_liked %}
        <button type="submit" id="like" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-danger">Dislike</button>
    {% else %}
        <button type="submit" id="like" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Like</button>
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

I would like the button to work on the principle of not reloading the whole page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I think is that you've not actually *called* `event.preventDefault` in your click event handler (you're missing the brackets). That means that the submit button submits the form, but the form doesn't contain a parameter named `id` and so `get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('id'))` raises a 404.

Add the missing brackets to `event.preventDefault`, and also note that the value of `id=` attributes on HTML elements should be [unique within the page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id). Change the values of the `id=` attributes on the `<button>` elements so that they are unique.